# Where are the site stats ?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, statistics, private-beta

Sites in beta usually have a little 'site stats' box on the side so one can monitor the site health. How come this site doesn't have one ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those will appear once the site has moved to public beta - for now, invite friends!

Answer (score 2):

You can see some rough statistics on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636?phase=beta).